# Can't source using yarn or npm on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, npm, environment-variables

Npm and yarn seems to rely on `/bin/sh` to trigger scripts, for compatibility reasons.
However, on Ubuntu, `source` is not available when using `sh`, we need `bash`. Here I need `source` to set up a Python virtual env, but the problme is more general.

I am looking for a solution to allow the use of `source`, **without breaking the script on other platforms.**

My ideas are:

- to force the use of bash instead, e.g. with `SHELL=/bin/bash`
- to use `.` instead of `source` but it doesn't seems to work when activating Python virtual env for example

But my understanding is not good enough to be sure that my solution is cross-platform.

Do you have any information on how npm or yarn handle scripts, and maybe how to use `source` on Ubuntu ?

Comment: `source` is an alternative name for `.` in `bash` and has the same functionality in `sh`.  Please give the exact problems you have with Python virtual env and show it working with `source` yet failing with `.`.

Comment: Hi, when you run `. whatever/activate`,  I have no error message but the env isn't activated. Then, when you try to `deactivate`, you get an error message telling that `deactivate` must be sourced.

Comment: Before you do the `.` put a `set -o xtrace`.  This will trace the commands within the file to stderr.  It could be, for example, there is an `if` condition not being met, or some other reason why items are not being set.  It should at least give some idea what is going on - and it will prove (or otherwise) that `.` is actually working.

Comment: Hi, according to the set -o xtrace, the `.` seems to be working, though in an incorrect "scope": the environnment is set in what seems to be the `yarn` or `npm` shell, but not in the current shell I am executing.
Note that even if my script is smth like `yarn set-venv && do-something`, it still won't work, the environment is not activated when calling `do-something`.

Comment: Can you try `type .` and `type source`?  I don't understand how `yarn` or `npm` fit into this.  I thought you could not get `.` to work in `bash`, so where are these others called?